# Binding a div row to a single item in an observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm developing a 3 part upload form, where users can upload 3 sets of files

So far, I've got the following viewModel

```
var FileGroupViewModel = function (id) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.files = ko.observableArray();

    self.removeFile = function (item) {
        self.files.remove(item);
    }

    self.fileUpload = function (data, e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];

        self.files.push(file);
    };
}

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.fileGroups = ko.observableArray();

    self.getFileGroupById = function (id) {
        ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.fileGroups(), function (item) {
            return item.id == id;
        });
    };

    self.uploadFiles = function () {
        alert('Uploading');
    }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
viewModel.fileGroups.push(new FileGroupViewModel(1));
viewModel.fileGroups.push(new FileGroupViewModel(2));
viewModel.fileGroups.push(new FileGroupViewModel(3));

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I have 3 'groups' of files a user can upload to.
(I will do the actual upload functionality later)

I'm struggling with how to `bind` my row to a specific item of the array?
Maybe I shouldn't use an observable array?

```
<div class="row files" id="files1" data-bind="???">
   <h2>Files 1</h2>
   <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
   Browse  <input data-bind="event: {change: fileUpload}" type="file"  />
   </span>
   <br />
   <div class="fileList" data-bind="foreach: files"> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: removeFile">Remove</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

The idea is when a user selects files, they appear in a list under the button:

[image: screenshot]

..with a link to remove the file from the upload queue.

I've set up a fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/c9fvzjte/

Comment: Instead of an observable array, maybe an array of observables?

Comment: Sure, sounds promising, but how do I bind to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few important modifications required to make your code work `independently` across files 0,1,2

**KeyNote**

> `event: { change: function(){fileUpload($data,$element.files[0])}}`
>   here we are passing our selected file i.e `filedata` using `$element` in
>   `change` event not in usual click event . Filedata will have complete file information .

**view:**

```
<div class="row files" id="files1" data-bind="foreach:fileGroups">
   <h2>Files 0</h2>
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
   Browse  <input  data-bind="event: { change: function() { fileUpload($data,$element.files[0]) } }" type="file"  />
</span>
<div class="fileList" data-bind="foreach: files"> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
 <a href="#" data-bind="click: removeFile.bind($data,$parent)">Remove</a>
</div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var SubFunction = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = data.name;
    self.removeFile = function (item1) {
        item1.files.remove(this); //current reference data & item1 has parent reference data
    }
}
var FileGroupViewModel = function (id) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.files = ko.observableArray([new SubFunction({
        'name': 'Test'
    })]);
    self.fileUpload = function (item1, item2) {
        self.files.push(new SubFunction(item2));
    };
}

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.fileGroups = ko.observableArray();
    self.getFileGroupById = function (id) {
        ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.fileGroups(), function (item) {
            return item.id == id;
        });
    };
    self.uploadFiles = function () {
        alert('Uploading');
    }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
viewModel.fileGroups.push(new FileGroupViewModel(1));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

working sample up for grabs **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/supercool/c9fvzjte/10/)**

Working sample if you are planning to **[reuse your Html](https://jsfiddle.net/supercool/c9fvzjte/8/)**

Comment: sorry, i should have stated in the original question - I can't use `foreach`  - There's some other text / content going in between each 'group' - which is why i was trying to bind to a single item in the array....

Comment: simple . you must go with `with` binding check here https://jsfiddle.net/supercool/c9fvzjte/16/ . @Alex let me know

Comment: this pointed my in the right direction, although I'm having a small other issue now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392198/function-bound-to-click-action-in-foreach-not-being-called