# Function bound to click action in foreach not being called

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having trouble binding my click action to the view model function to remove an item from an array (inside a `foreach` binding)

I've got the following view model

```
var FileGroupViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.files = ko.observableArray();

    self.removeFile = function (item) {
        self.files.remove(item);
    }

    self.fileUpload = function (data, e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];

        self.files.push(file);
    };
}

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.FileGroup = ko.observableArray();

    self.FileGroup1 = new FileGroupViewModel();
    self.FileGroup2 = new FileGroupViewModel();
    self.FileGroup3 = new FileGroupViewModel();


    self.uploadFiles = function () {
        alert("Uploading");
    }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And my view, which basically lists 3 "groups" of buttons, where a user can select files to upload

Everything below is working as expected, except `$parent.removeFile` isn't removing the file:

```
<div class="row files">
    <h2>Files 1</h2>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        Browse  <input data-bind="event: {change: FileGroup1.fileUpload}" type="file" />
    </span>

    <br />
    <div class="fileList" data-bind="foreach: FileGroup1.files">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeFile">Remove</a>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/aw0798p7/

Am I wrong to do `$parent.removeFile` - it seems this doesn't get called on click?

This is a cut down working example, not the finished product!

Comment: try `click:$root.FileGroup1.removeFile`.

Comment: @Dandy yes, this was it. Thanks

Comment: just for your reference https://jsfiddle.net/3c4o21wb/1/ ... answers already given are great!

Comment: @Sam.C thanks, I can't use `foreach:FileGroup` round the FileGroups - this is only a cut down example - thanks anyway though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding `$parent`. It takes you out one context level. Your `foreach` uses `FileGroup1.files` as its index, so you might think that the `$parent` level would be `Filegroup1`, but it's not. It's the top-level viewmodel, because that is the context outside the `foreach`.

So your `click` binding should be

```
click: $parent.FileGroup1.removeFile
```